# Pass a bounded cursor to a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

There are many examples to open a cursor inside a function, but I can't find the opposite.

Take a look to this simple function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.try_ref_cursor(IN rc refcursor)
    RETURNS bigint
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
declare
/*
    IN rc refcursor
    RETURNS bigint
    
*/
    _rec record;
    _i  integer=0;
begin

    open rc;

    for _rec in rc loop
        _raise notice '%', _rec
        _i=_i+1;
    end loop;

    return _i;
end;
$BODY$;
```

the function call:

```
declare
    mycursor cursor for select a, b,c from sometable;
    mycount integer;
begin
    mycount=public.try_ref_cursor(mycursor);
end;
```

My actual need is to iterate on a recordset (coming from different tables) with some fields always present (think to the interface pattern) and do some checks and aggregations, returning at the end a jsonb.

Ok I can rewrite the function passing an array of record, but it doesn't seem very efficient.

any ideas?

Comment: [Loop through query results](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING). As per [Cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-FOR-LOOP): *However, PL/pgSQL users do not normally need to worry about that, since FOR loops automatically use a cursor internally to avoid memory problems.*.

Comment: Why do you need a cursor? I'm not saying you never need it, but in my work I didn't need it for the last 15 or so years. We process billions of records daily.

Answer (score 0):

refcursor is name of cursor, and it is just text. You can pass it in both directions without any problems.